# Why can't I access the correct value of pi in tcl?

Tags: tcl

Here is the code I have executed:

```
C:\intelFPGA\18.1\quartus\bin64>tclsh86
% puts $tcl_version
8.6
% package require math::constants
1.0.2
% puts [pi]
26576
% puts [PI]
invalid command name "PI"
% puts [math::constants::pi]
invalid command name "math::constants::pi"
% puts [math::constants::constants::pi]
invalid command name "math::constants::constants::pi"
```

Why do I get the wrong value of pi? Why can't I get access to the correct value even if I use the :: operator to get into the math package? I just installed the tcl libraries but I am still having trouble.

Comment: `pi` is not a function

Comment: I had thought that the value of pi will be put into the [ ] but you made me realize that the [ ] is used to invoke command execution upon which the new contents would be put into here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variable, not a command:

```
% puts $::math::constants::pi
3.141592653589793
```

Or import it directly into your current namespace:

```
% ::math::constants::constants pi
% puts $pi
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: What is that 26576 that I am getting? I do not understand.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 `[pi]` in a toplevel command resolves to calling the [`pid`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/pid.htm) command, so that's your process ID. Details of how unknown commands are resolved is in [`unknown`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/unknown.htm).

Comment: Is it of any use to know the process id inside the tcl environment

Comment: Not super useful in core tcl, but if you're using the tclx extension and its support for unix system programming, knowing pids can be useful for some tasks.

Comment: I am looking for a program that can be used to debug TCL code. This means do things like step through code, view trace of function calls, watch variables type and value, add breakpoints, look at variable type by hovering over e.t.c. Could you kindly recommend something that you are familiar with. Thanks.